# afterScriptsLoaded called multiple times when accessing a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component with a table and one of the columns is an  link to a record detail page (ie, /mop-grp/recordid). Within the record detail page, there is a lightning component.  The component has an afterScriptsLoaded, and it is being called 3 times when I click on the  link. This issue is intermittent.  Sometimes it is called once. Any ideas why.  There are no controller methods with the same name as the apex method.

The columns of the table are dynamically created. getColumns()
GrpTable.cmp - Helper method:

```
getColumns : function(cmp) {
        return [
                { "data": "Id", "type" : "selector", "NoSelectAll" : true},
                { "data": "Name", "title": $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_Group_Name"), "mobileHeader" : true, "dataType" : "String",
                    "renderFn": function(col){
                        return"<a class='nav-link' href='" + $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_base_ORG_Link") + $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_Base_Extention") + "mop-group/" + col.Id + "'>" + col.Name + "</a>";
                    }
                },
                { "data": "No_Of_Contacts__c", "title": $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_No_of_Contacts"), "default": 0, "apiName":"No_Of_Contacts__c"},
                { "data": "CreatedDate", "title": $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_Date_Created"), "apiName":"CreatedDate", "class" : "fixed-width-140", "dateFormat":"userLocale"},
                { "data": "LastModifiedDate", "title": $A.get("$Label.c.MOP_Last_Modified_Date"), "apiName":"LastModifiedDate", "class" : "fixed-width-140", "dateFormat":"userLocale"},
                { "data": "Id", "type":"delete", "id":"contacts_mygroups_delete" }
            ];
    },
```

This getColumns method is passed as a parameter to another component, Lightning_Table_Import, which forms the table -- with the columns, and the data:

```
createTableView : function(cmp, data) {
        var context = this;

        context.getDataList(cmp, data);

        $A.createComponent(
            'c:Lightning_Table_Import',
            {
                'aura:id'               :'groupsTable',
                'id'                    : cmp.get('v.id'),
                'columns'               : this.getColumns(cmp),
                'data'                  : data
            },
            function(tableView, status, errorMessage) {
                if (status == 'SUCCESS') {
                    cmp.set('v.tableView', tableView);
                }
             }
        );
    },
```

When the above renders, each column looks something like this:  This one is specifically for the one with the  tag that I'm having an issue with:

```
<td style="cursor:default" role="gridcell">
    <div>
      <span class="table-column-name">Group Name: </span>
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://dev-testdev.cs1.force.com/myofficepro/s/mop-group/a0RS0000004fRD8MAM">EG2</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

The link above when clicked, goes to that record detail page.  Inside the page, I have a component, called MOP_GroupDetails.cmp with an afterScriptsLoaded event:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                    $Resource.MOP + '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
                    $Resource.MOP + '/js/DataCache.js',
                    $Resource.MOP + '/js/jquery.mask.js',
                    $Resource.MOP + '/js/arbonne-demo.js',
                    $Resource.MOP + '/js/lodash.js'
                )}"
        styles="{!join(',',
                          $Resource.MOP + '/css/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css',
                          $Resource.MOP + '/css/ourcomp.css')}"
        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptLoad}"
    />
```

afterScriptLoad method is called 3 times.  Here's the code:

```
afterScriptLoad: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('mop group details afterScriptLoad ' + event.target );

        helper.loadGroupDetails(component, event);
        if (window.history.state == null)
            component.set('v.backClass', 'disabled slds-text-color--weak ');
        else
            component.set('v.backClass', '');

    },
```

I see the console.log('mop group details afterScriptLoad ' + event.target ) called 3 times...not always, but at times.  It happens (I think) when GrpTable.cmp was refreshed (via an event handler to refresh the view) prior to clicking that '' link.

The original requirement by business is that they want a 'Back' button (which acts like the "<-" Back button of the browser) in our components, which redirects the user back to where it was called from.  Because this page was called 3 times, the 'Back' button  redirects back to itself 3 times.

Comment: Please, could you provide your code?

Comment: @Robs, so we dynamically build our table, and we set how a column will be rendered.  For this particular column, the column is rendered this way: 
function(col){
  return"<a class='nav-link' href='" + $A.get("$Label.c.base_ORG_Link") + $A.get("$Label.c.Base_Extention") + "mop-group/" + col.Id + "'>" + col.Name + "</a>";
}
The link above redirects to the record detail page of MOP_Group.  Inside the record detail page is a component. This component's afterScriptsLoaded is triggered 3 times.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a more complete code example

Comment: From the description in your question, it sounds to me as though you just answered your own question as to why this is happening at times. Any time the page reloads or is refreshed, the after script will be executed once again.

Comment: But why would a refreshView on a table cause clicking an <a> link to trigger 3 times? The link is still just a link.